# Efficient list comparison in python

Tags: python, list, performance, comparison

I'd like to efficiently compare two lists and determine if both share exactly the same elements.

The lists can be `None`, empty and of various lengths. Ordering of the elements inside the list does not matter, so `['a', 'b', 'c'] == ['a', 'c', 'b']` are equal in my case.

My current solution looks like this:

```py
 def list_a_equals_list_b(list_a, list_b):
    if list_a != None and list_b != None:
        if len(list_a) != len(list_b):
            return False
        else:
            return len(frozenset(list_a).intersection(list_b)) == len(list_a)
    elif list_a == None and list_b == None:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Is there a more efficient way to compare those lists?

Thanks!

Comment: Can  you have repeated elements in your lists?

Comment: You got me here ;-). Didn't think about duplicates yet, as in my current use case I can exclude them. Obviously the code from above, won't work with those. So at the moment: no duplicates :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have duplicates in either lists you can use a set:

```
if listA == listB  \
or listA and listB \
   and len(listA) == len(listB) \
   and not set(listA).symmetric_difference(listB):
   # lists have the same elements
else:
   # there are differences
```

If you do allow duplicates, then yo can use Counter from collections (which would also work if you don't have duplicates)

```
from collections import Counter

if listA == listB  \
or listA and listB \
   and len(listA) == len(listB) \
   and Counter(listA)==Counter(listB):
   # lists have the same elements
else:
   # there are differences
```

Comment: symmetric_difference was the function I was looking for, Thx! For sure I'll keep the length comparision. The issue was the 'frozenset(list_a).intersection(list_b)' part :-)

Comment: Using the `symmetric_difference` method unnecessarily creates a new set just so you can test if it's empty, resulting in more overhead. Simply doing `set(list_a) == set(list_b)` would be enough.

Comment: With both list being the same length, symetric_difference will be more efficient because it does not require creation of a set for listB and will never create a resulting set that is larger than set(listB) even when both lists are completely different.  So, from a set creation perspective its worst case scenario is equivalent to creating set(listB) and all other cases will be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

The Counter() method is best if your objects are hashable.
but here sorted() built-in function is your best option.

```
def list_a_equals_list_b(list_a, list_b):
    return (list_a == None and list_b == None) or sorted(list_a) == sorted(list_b)
```